# Why does Chrome keep eating more and more memory when using the CME?

Tags: 2011, cme

When I have Chrome open for a long time using the SDL Tridion (2011SP1) CME, it seems that the memory creeps up and up until I have to kill the process (within a few hours can go up to 1 GB of RAM), or it just croaks of its own accord. Any ideas why, and if I can stop this?

Comment: Isn't it just that when you have Chrome open for a long time it eats up a lot of memory, unrelated to what website you browse, ie. unrelated to SDL Tridion? Can you reproduce this issue when only have one Chrome browser open with SDL Tridion and no other windows/tabs, and then confirm it is not occurring when you have Chrome open to any other website?

Comment: I've got no issues. I've had the same Chrome instance with the CME open for days now and all is fine (mind you, I have to hit Refresh every once in a while to reestablish the session)

Comment: @Bart: Exactly, this is the exact scenario happening with me except that it is occurring even if it is opened with the a single tab

Answer (score 8):

Per my experience so far, this is with the latest version of Chrome. Chrome is giving lots of error, the earlier version was not able to render HTML tags correctly and this new one is eating up a lots of memory - Not only for CME but for any site (at least for me).

Further, if you are using it on Windows 7, that will make the thing worsen because of few memory distribution issues in Win 7 (and that's why even FF and IE are eating up lots of memory, but lesser than Chrome).

You may want to follow a discussion going on [HERE](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7n6LEvjjEoY)

However, you may want to take following measure to ensure the best you can do from your end:

- Check the list of all the Plug Ins/Extension added to Chrome. Remove those which are not in use, and check for possible bugs in any of the Plugin
- Disable all the extension, when you are not using them
- Check if you have an older version of Flash installed and is enabled in Chrome
- Removes all older data/history/cookies etc.

Further you may want follow few more guidelines specified [HERE](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/03/31/reduce-save-conserve-memory-google-chrome/)

Because of this behaviour of Chrome since last couple of Months, I have already shifted to FF, and not much impressed with it, thinking of going to IE10 :P

Answer (score 5):

As per my experience and also commented by Pankaj, this is not an issue of CME

1. Don't keep Chrome open for long time. else it will eat up all
   available memory.
2. Adobe Flash is also an issue with chrome(not sure
   about ff). it crashes alot and consume memory.
3. if you are chrome
   fanboy like me, open chrome in incognito mode. in this mode by
   default all the extensions plugins will be disabled until unless you
   have not choose option to run extensions in this mode.